Docker SH health_check_cmd unknown shorthand flag
I'm using sh scripts for Docker container build and run, and I want to add a heartbeat detection command to the cli, but when I splice it using variables it doesn't recognize it correctly, yet the cli commands I output via echo start up fine.
Here is the script code
# Heartbeat URL
health_check_cmd="curl -f http://172.17.0.1:5110/v2/alarm/hostRecord/find || exit 1"
# Heartbeat check interval, default: 30 seconds
health_check_interval=30s

dockerContainerOpe(){
    echo 'Starting operations on Docker container'
    # Stop and remove container
    if docker ps -a --format '{{.Names}}' | grep -q "^$container_name\$"; then
        docker rm -f $container_name
    fi
    # Build container
    docker build -t $docker_version_name --build-arg jarName=$jar_name .
    # Prepare docker run command
    run_cmd="docker run -itd $port_args --name=$container_name -v $docker_volume_path"
    # Add health check command and interval
    if [[ -n "$health_check_cmd" ]]; then
        run_cmd="$run_cmd --health-cmd=\"$health_check_cmd\" --health-interval=$health_check_interval"
    fi
    # Add other parameters
    run_cmd="$run_cmd --restart=always --privileged=true $docker_version_name"
    echo "Running command: $run_cmd"
    $run_cmd
    # Remove dangling containers
    if [[ -n $(docker images | grep "none" | awk '{print $3}') ]]; then
        docker rmi $(docker images | grep "none" | awk '{print $3}')
    fi
}

Running command:

docker run -itd  -p 5150:5150 --name=cmmop-alarm -v
/home/logs:/home/logs --health-cmd="curl -f
http://172.17.0.1:5110/v2/alarm/hostRecord/find || exit 1"
--health-interval=30s --restart=always --privileged=true cmmop-alarm:1.0.0

unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f
See 'docker run --help'.
docker 
Server Version: 20.10.17

Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

What am I doing wrong?

The way you're trying to build a command line doesn't work. Consider the following command:
touch "this is" "a test"

Run this from your shell prompt and it will create two files, named this is and a test. If I attempt to build the command like you're doing in your script:
run_cmd="touch \"this is\" \"a test\"""

And then run the variable:
$run_cmd

I will end up with:
$ ls -1
'"a'
'is"'
'test"'
'"this'

The shell doesn't "see" quotes contained in a variable when you use it like that; they are simply considered part of any adjacent words, and any whitespace is treated like an argument separator.
There are a few ways of solving this. One is the use of the eval command:
eval "$run_cmd"

This will do exactly what we want. Alternatively, if you're using Bash, you can build up your command line using arrays instead:
run_cmd=(touch "this is" "a test")
"${run_cmd[@]}"

We can rewrite your shell script using that technique like this:
#!/bin/bash

# Heartbeat URL
health_check_cmd="curl -f http://172.17.0.1:5110/v2/alarm/hostRecord/find || exit 1"

# Heartbeat check interval, default: 30 seconds
health_check_interval=30s

# I added some default values in order to test the script locally
jar_name=myproject.jar
docker_version_name=example:latest
container_name=example
port_args="9090:8080"
docker_volume_path="$PWD:/src"

dockerContainerOpe() {
    echo 'Starting operations on Docker container'

    # Stop and remove existing container
    docker container inspect "$container_name" 2>/dev/null &&
    docker container rm -f "$container_name"

    # Build container
    docker build -t "$docker_version_name" --build-arg "jarName=$jar_name" .

    # Prepare docker run command
    run_cmd=(
        docker run -d -p "$port_args"
        "--name" "$container_name" -v "$docker_volume_path"
        --restart=always --privileged=true
    )

    # Add health check command and interval
    if [[ -n "$health_check_cmd" ]]; then
        run_cmd+=(--health-cmd "$health_check_cmd" --health-interval "$health_check_interval")
    fi

    # Add other parameters
    run_cmd+=("$docker_version_name")

    echo "Running command: ${run_cmd[*]}"
    "${run_cmd[@]}"
}

dockerContainerOpe

